# Chaining autocompletions in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am working on a web application where people can ask questions and get answers. In order to improve usability, we are trying to get server-backed auto-completion on the client side that would help the user build its query.

One example would be, the user starts entering "fo" and we suggest the known concept "foo bar" and than when selecting that option, we query the auto completion service with the selected concept and than present the user with "What is foo bar" and "Where to find foo bar".

We are using the autocompletion plugin in JQuery but are running against a problem when hitting the server the second time. In the **select** option of JQuery autocompletion, we launch another search with the new value but even though we get results the option panel is not shown.

We have tried destroying and recreating it in the search, tried triggering "input" and "change" events, tried preventing the panel to close and tried forcing the panel open but nothing seems to work.

```
this.searchBox.autocomplete({
    delay: 200,
    minLength: 0,
    response: function (event, ui) {},
    search: function (event, ui) {},
    select: function (select, ui) {
        self.searchBox.val(ui.item.value);
        self.searchBox.autocomplete("search");
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        u.async.get(url, {
            lan: "en",
            q: request.term
        }).success(function (data) {
            response(data.Suggestions);
            self.enable(data.Validity);
        }).failure(function (data) {
            console.log("fetch failure", data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality, searching again with the same term as the current query is specifically disabled in JQuery.

From the source code,

```
_searchTimeout: function( event ) {
  clearTimeout( this.searching );
  this.searching = this._delay(function() {
    // only search if the value has changed
    if ( this.term !== this._value() ) {
      this.selectedItem = null;
      this.search( null, event );
    }
  }, this.options.delay );
},
```

Therefore, my solution, is to take advantage of the fact that JQuery is doing reference equality and in my code make it so that `this.term` is set to `new String(this._value())`.

If Jquery starts to do lexical equality, this will break but if anyone has a better solution short of modifying JQuery's code, I am all ears.